# How to update foreign keys while inserting rows?

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I have two tables with the following layout ...

```
-------------    -------------------------
| Master    |    | History               |
-------------    -------------------------
| id | name |    | id | name | master_id |
-------------    -------------------------
```

The `history` table contains rows where the `master_id` is `NULL`. Those I copy into the `master` table.

```sql
INSERT master (name)
SELECT name
FROM histories h
WHERE h.master_id = NULL
```

How can I update the `master_id` in the `history` table with the `id` of the associated object in the `master` table? This update should happen in the same step as the insertion is made. I use MySQL if this is of interest.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to insert into `master` table records with IDs based on some information from the other table.

For example, you can use the histories.id + last master.id:

```
LOCK TABLES master WRITE, histories AS h WRITE;

SELECT id FROM master ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1 INTO @last_master_id;

INSERT INTO master (id, name)
    SELECT h.id + @last_master_id, h.name FROM histories h;

UPDATE histories h SET h.master_id = h.id + @last_master_id;

UNLOCK TABLES;
```

This works as long as you use integer IDs and if you don't mind that the new ID is based on the other one.

If you wanted to use some non-deterministic IDs, such as UUIDs, the solution would require a few more steps:

- Add a temporary column to the `histories` table.
- Fill with the new IDs (`update histories set tmp_uuid = UUID()`, something like that).
- Insert into `master` select `tmp_uuid` from `histories`...
- Update `histories`
- Drop the temporary column.

One advantage of using UUIDs is that you don't need to lock the tables. You don't need to worry about other session inserting a record and taking your ID, because the other session generates a different ID.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL documentation here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html

suggests that you should be able to do something like the following:

```
INSERT master (name)
SELECT name, id
FROM history h
WHERE h.master_id = NULL

UPDATE History SET master_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() 
WHERE History.id = h.id;
```

Though I'm not 100% on the syntax as I don't have a SQL instance I can run this against.